# Gitlab CI: Run Pipeline job only for tagged commits that exist on protected branches

Tags: tags, conditional-statements, gitlab-ci

I would like to create a pipeline that is only run if *both* of the following conditions are met:

- A tag refers to the given commit
- The commit exists on any protected branch (i.e. master)
- Optional: The job should be run whenever a tagged unprotected branch is merge (with a merge request) into a protected branch or if a tag is added to a protected branch.

I've tried:

```yaml
publish:
  stage: publish
  script:
    - echo "Publish!"
  rules:
    # Only publish if tag given and commit is present on a protected branch
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG && $CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED == "true"'
```

Which does not work as either the `$CI_COMMIT_TAG` is set **or** the `$CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED` is set to true.

I am aware of the similar Questions: [Gitlab ci run job on master with release tag only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60722228/gitlab-ci-run-job-on-master-with-release-tag-only) and [How to run a gitlab-ci.yml job only on a tagged branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796018/how-to-run-a-gitlab-ci-yml-job-only-on-a-tagged-branch).

Also I know there is/was a wide discussion in the issues from gitlab, with some solution (or something close to this) like [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/27818#note_38488985).

The general problem seems to be that it is not possible in gitlab to determine reliable if a commit if on a given branch as the information (git history) for this is not given.

This question is to keep track of a proper solution within gitlab CI for this common use case.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Combining the [workaround mentioned](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/27818#note_38488985) in the question with the new [gitlab rule](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#prevent-duplicate-pipelines) and [workflow](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#workflowrules) features I came up with an answer that seems satisfying for me.

The person originally posting the workaround mentioned that there are cases in which `git branch contains` does not give the correct results.
So I made sure, that `git fetch` does not make a shallow copy (note for the beginning it could be useful to change the `GIT_STRATEGY` to *clone*, so that old possible shallow copies are removed).

Instead of using `CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED` which could be true also for protected tags, I hardcoded the `$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH` (thx to [Gostega) as protected.

```yaml
# Be quite strict in what can trigger a pipeline, actually only pushes of
# branches or version tags should trigger anything - otherwise we need to catch
# too many edge cases.
workflow:
  rules:
    # Do no allow manually triggered pipelines to prevent duplicates!
    # Instead rerun the pipeline created with the last push
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "push"
      when: never
    # Only execute when a valid version tag like v1.0, 2.3 or similar is given
    # Required is always one point like 1.0
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^v?[0-9]+[.][0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$/
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
variables:
  # Make sure we don't get a shallow copy
  GIT_DEPTH: 0
  # Fetch is default just to make clear what is used
  GIT_STRATEGY: fetch
  # make sure we fetch everything and also see what is happening
  GIT_FETCH_EXTRA_FLAGS: -f --tags --prune --update-head-ok

default:
  before_script:
    - export CI_LOG_LINE=$(git log --decorate=full| grep "^commit $CI_COMMIT_SHA[ ]")
    # var = 1 if the current commit is the **latest** on the default branch
    - export IS_ON_MAIN=$(echo $CI_LOG_LINE | grep -qso "origin/${CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH}, " && echo 1 || echo 0)
    # var = 1 if current commit is on any remote commit that is part of default branchs history
    - export COMMIT_ON_MAIN=$(git branch -r --contains $CI_COMMIT_SHA | grep -Eq "^[ ]+origin/${CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH}$"  && echo 1 || echo 0)


stages:
  - check_update_environment
  - test
  - publish

check_update_environment:
  stage: check_update_environment
  script:
    # Exit if tag is given on none main branch early
    # Check for 
    - if [[ ! -z "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" && $COMMIT_ON_MAIN != 1 ]]; then
         echo "Tags should never be applied to non main branches!" >&2;
         echo "We quit early! Please delete the tag, merge the branch to main and recreate the tag to continue" >&2;
         exit 1;
      fi

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Doing testing..."
  dependencies:
    - check_update_environment

publish:
  stage: publish
  script:
    - echo "Publishing..."
  rules:
    # Run always if there is version tag. The version tag is defined
    #   in the workflow rules
    # Due to the fail early in the environment check this is never done for
    # branches that aren't the default branch
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
  dependencies:
    - test
```

Comment: Hey @Kound you still using this workaround, or have you developed anything better? By the way, instead of hardcoding to master, I use `if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH`. Which lets me reuse it across any project (we have started moving to `main` as the default branch name so have a mix of names).

Comment: Hey @Gostega thanks for the tip. I will test it soon and update the answer. I didn't develop a more sophisticated solution and this one is still in operation. 
Btw: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME will be the tag for pipeline triggered by the tag. So this is not useful to check if the tag pipeline is on master. (See also https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)

Comment: This is a really complicated solution. I've kind of settled on just making the tags themselves protected. Quite annoying we cannot combine the conditions on branches and tags.

Comment: Well all the limitations are originated in the nature of git itself. IMHO my solution is not that complicated. I still removed some debug stuff in order to remove some noise.