# gitlab-ci.yml jobs:build-production config key may not be used with `rules`: only

Tags: build, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I am having a syntax error when I test my gitlab-ci.yml in CI Lint.  Can someone suggest a solution to this problem?

```
build-production:
  stage: build
  only:
    - master
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"username\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_USER\",\"password\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - /kaniko/executor --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_TAG
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
```

```
Status: syntax is incorrect 

jobs:build-production config key may not be used with `rules`: only
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

[Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) is pretty clear :

> `rules` replaces `only`/`except` and they can’t be used together in the same job. If you configure one job to use both keywords, the linter returns a key may not be used with rules error.

I suggest to use `rules:` for both of your conditions :

```
rules:
  - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master" && $CI_COMMIT_TAG'
```

Comment: The documentation is clear, it's a shame the error message is not. First rule of intuitive design, if your solution is "we'll document that" you're making a mistake.

Comment: what is `&& $CI_COMMIT_TAG` does here?

Comment: it means if the pipeline is executed on a git tag.

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct, unless you would create a tag `master`.

See: https://gitlab.sron.nl/help/ci/variables/predefined_variables.md

> `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME`
> The branch or tag name for which project is built.

There is a workaround described here: [Gitlab CI: Run Pipeline job only for tagged commits that exist on protected branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62756669/gitlab-ci-run-pipeline-job-only-for-tagged-commits-that-exist-on-protected-bran)