# GitLab jobs:build config key may not be used with `rules`: only

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, cicd

I have a GitLab CI job that I want to only run for `tags` or for two special branches (`develop`, `main`).

```yaml
only:
  - develop
  - main
  - tags
```

This job has a dynamic variable that I set using the `rules` feature:

```yaml
variables:
  IMAGE_TAG: $CI_COMMIT_TAG # defaults to the pushed commit tag name
rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == 'develop'
    variables:
      IMAGE_TAG: 'develop'
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == 'main'
    variables:
      IMAGE_TAG: 'main'
```

The linter gives me this error though:

> jobs:build config key may not be used with `rules`: only

I looked around and it looks like [you can't use `rules` together with `only`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67010580/gitlab-ci-yml-jobsbuild-production-config-key-may-not-be-used-with-rules-onl).

If I remove the `only` directive, then this job will also run on any branch. How do I adjust my script so that I can set the variable dynamically but also limit the job to only run on tags and certain branches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent `rules:` to this would be:

```
rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"
    # ... insert `variables:` here if you want...
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
    # ...
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
```

In this case, you also don't need to set your `IMAGE_TAG` variable conditionally. You can just use `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` which will be equal to `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` for branch pipelines or `$CI_COMMIT_TAG` for tag pipelines.